# like Operator in ahoy events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ahoy

I started code rails recently and I need to figure out this problem.

```
%td
  = Ahoy::Event.where(name: "viewed_brochure").where_properties(brochure_id: brochure.id, time: like 'Mon%').count
```

this should be show the number of Mondays in database. But it doesn't work and give syntax error.

I wonder how to use like operator in this line.

```
Ahoy::Event.where(time: "2017-10-30 14:50:35.361999").where_properties(brochure_id: brochure.id).count
```

This line works fine but i need to use like operator or something similar.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: But 'time' is a datetime type.. what would you achieve comparing it with string 'Mon%'?

Comment: I need to determine this datetime data convert to day of week.

Comment: What's your database?

Comment: My db is PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Ahoy::Event.where("date_part('dow', time) = 1").count
```

This will return the count of all events created at Monday.You can add more filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use built in postgres function for that:

```
Ahoy::Event.where("EXTRACT(DOW FROM time) = 1").where_properties(brochure_id: brochure.id).count
```

Comment: Thank u so much guys. This two solutions works fine.